# BroadcastReceiver gets 3 ACTION_SCREEN_OFFs whenever I lock the screen and only 1 ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

So I'm making an app that sends a message when you press the lock button twice, however when I run the app and check the logs, SCREEN OFF is shown three times in the log. And since SCREEN OFF is shown three times, it means that counter was incremented three times, so the message is sent one just one press if your phone was unlocked. Why is this?

```
if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
    {
        Log.d("IT WORKED", "SCREEN OFF");
        if (listen == true)
            counter++;
    }

    else
    {
        if (listen == true)
            counter++;
        Log.d("IT WORKED", "SCREEN ON");
    }
//when counter == 2 (2 lock button presses) send message
```

Comment: Before increment counter check how many times the broadcast receiver onReceive() method runs

Comment: @HemanthSTobi it runs three times, since it Logs "SCREEN OFF" thrice. But that's only when I turn off the screen, when I turn it on, it only Logs "SCREEN ON" once, which I find really weird

Comment: How many intent filters you have registered

Comment: @HemanthSTobi just android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON and android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF maybe its my device, but either way still pretty weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experiment this works and gives you only two counts

```
int counter = 0;
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            switch (action) {
                case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
                    counter++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: " + counter);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Same problem and I just copy pasted, guess it's device-related. Either way I just added some extra logic that only adds to counter the 2nd time it receives the SCREEN_OFF, so I got it to work fine.